# Nombre de blob para PDF

Tags: typescript, pdf

Estoy abriendo un blob con un PDF, necesito asignarle un nombre a la url ya que ese es el que utiliza por defecto a la hora de descargarse.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
abrirPdf(base64Data: string, name: string, target: string, window: Window & typeof globalThis) {
let arrayBufferPDF = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Data);
let blob = new Blob([arrayBufferPDF], { type: 'application/pdf' });
let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let newWindow = window.open(fileURL, target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo es simulando un click en un elemento `a` que creas tú, y al que le pones el nombre que tú quieres:

```
abrirPdf(base64Data: string, name: string, target: string, window: Window & typeof globalThis) {
  // Este es tu código, pero prefiero usar const para estas cosas
  const arrayBufferPDF = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Data);
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferPDF], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // Ahora creamos un elemento <a>
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  // Le seteamos el archivo que debe descargar:
  a.href = fileURL;
  // Y le seteamos el nombre!
  a.download = 'NOMBRE_DE_TU_PDF_AQUI';
  // Solo falta clickarlo:
  a.click();
}
```

De esa manera podemos poner el nombre que queramos en el archivo descargado :)